# Can I validate firestore.rules before making a push?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli, firebase-security

When you have a firebase project you depploy with the firebase tools, is it possible to validate the firestore.rules?

That would be very helpful to avoid related build/deploy problems.

Comment: Hey Daule. I don't think such a tool exists at the moment. But we're definitely looking at ways to improve the efficiency of implementing security rules. What type of build problems are you thinking of?

Comment: Hi Frank. So I new developer on my team was not aware that he could test the rules on console.firebase. So he just did some changes to the file, and off course none of the tests picked it up. So it failed during deployment. Would be nice to avoid in the future :)